# MATLAB - Variation of parameters in a range

Tags: matlab, parameters, range, system

Maybe it's a silly question but I just started studying MATLAB. How can I vary one or more parameters within a set range?

For example, I've to vary two real parameters, 'alpha' and 'beta', in the range [-20,20]. I need this variation in order to determine the stability of a system based on the variation of parameters.

Answer (score 1):

In the simplest way, if you want evenly spaced values of the parameters, first you need to decide how the parameters will vary within the range, either defined a step size or a number of points within the range (including the limits). If you define the step size and call it `Dalpha`, for example, then

```
alpha = (-20:Dalpha:20);
```

gives you the variation in that parameter. Note that it's possible that the upper limit will not be included. If you instead define the number of points within the interval and call it, say, `N` then

```
alpha = linspace(-20,20,N);
```

gives you `N` equally spaced values of that include both limits. It is possible to have the variation not in uniform steps that most likely require a loop.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, so helpful!
So If I have 
`alpha = (-20: 0.1: 20);`
and
`beta = (-20: 0.1: 20);`
how can I create a matrix, for example `A=[alpha 0 1; 1 1 beta; alpha+beta 1 0]`, with varying `alpha` and `beta`?

Comment: @Ciro-G: The code you show beginning `A=[... ` will create a matrix with three rows, the first row is `alpha` followed by `0 1`; the second is `1 1 ` followed by `beta`; the last row has the element-by-element sum of `alpha` and `beta` followed by `1 0`;